# C# - Easy method for using CSV/Excel data and choosing specific data?

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

I am currently working on a jeopardy type game and want to include a CSV file with questions, so there are more questions for the game if anyone intend to play it again. I am struggling to figure out a way to seperate this CSV file into categories of some sort. So far i have 2 questions for each button of points. Whenever a button is pressed i want it to retrieve the question from the file and randomizing between these 2 questions, and thereafter display the chosen question in a textbox.

If anyone has suggestions of methods i can use for making this possible, I am open ears!

So far i have tried pretty much all the C# CSV file tutorials on YouTube, the problem is that none of them treat the data in the same way that i want to, which makes it complicated for me.

I will of course provide whatever you need to help me. 
And in advance, thank you! :)

Comment: Since CSV is just a data table, you can use it any way you would like, so I think you need to clarify how you want to read it. I would recommend to read it line by line to a List, and then pick the wanted question by random the way you want.

Comment: Should have a column in your csv file for the category. You can then filter the csv records according to this and make a random choice. [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) can be of good help for reading and mapping the csv file into classes so that you don't have to deal with string parsing.

Comment: @einord The problem is specifically how i can read it, which is what I'm asking help for. I am in doubt of what the easiest course of action is. I've already tried reading it line by line to a list, but after that I'm helpless. I'm not sure how i can retrieve a specific question with the belonging answer as well and display them in textboxes...

Comment: @OguzOzgul I do have a header for each column yes. The problem is that i have 5 categories, 100 to 500 points, a question, an answer and then i also added an ID to each question, which I see now probably is useless.

I will take a look at CSV Helper though, thank you :)

Comment: You have the `Category` column yes? That's what you need. The rest is just API call excrecise.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I do. I realized half way in making the questions that most of the categories wasn't necessary. Although there are 10 questions for each category which makes up for 2 questions for each point category, which of course is 100, 200, 300, 400 and 500 points. Don't i need them too so the questions don't get mixed up in difficulty? :)

Comment: You of course need them. What I mean is, regarding your question the category field is essential. You also should have the Id by the way, otherwise how could you record which questions have you asked already? Or if you ask one question per category/points then it is ok, but still, for auditing purposes, just have the Id :)

Comment: @OguzOzgul I will try it out. Thanks alot :)

I don't know if it is too much to ask for, but if you've got the time I would love it if you were able to put up an example of code I can get some inspiration from. :)

Comment: ok. do you have an hour or two?

Comment: @OguzOzgul I'm just leaving for work right now, sadly... What did you have in mind

Comment: Just, if it can wait for one or two hours. I'm at work right now and can't do it immediately.

Comment: It's done. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT - 2020-04-08 22:57 (UTC+03:00)

Please find the working form below. Just copy / paste into form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

namespace EksamensprojektTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static Values[] allRecords;
        static Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

        private string currentCategory = "Danish";
        private int currentPoints = 100;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public sealed class CsvRecordMap : ClassMap<Values>
        {
            public CsvRecordMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.ID);
                Map(m => m.Question);
                Map(m => m.Answer);
                Map(m => m.Points);
                Map(m => m.Category);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\mathi\\OneDrive\\HTX\\3.g\\Programmering\\Eksamensprojekt\\csvfil.csv"))
            {
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvRecordMap>();
                    allRecords = csv.GetRecords<Values>().ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        public static Values GetRandomQuestion(string category, int points)
        {
            var matchingQuestions = allRecords
                .Where(x => x.Category == category && x.Points == points)
                .ToArray();

            if (matchingQuestions.Length == 0) { return null; }

            // if length is 2, random returns 0 or 1.
            // if length is 3, random returns 0 or 1 or 2, etc.
            int randomChoice = randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, matchingQuestions.Length);
            return matchingQuestions[randomChoice];
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Values pickedRecord = GetRandomQuestion(currentCategory, currentPoints);
            textBox1.Text = pickedRecord.Question;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The following method can bu used to get a random question having the specified category and points. The `allRecords` array is the same as the original answer and is filled the same way. This method is just an addition:

Please put this at the class level:

```
static Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
```

Then the method:

```
public static CsvRecord GetRandomQuestion(string category, int points)
{
    var matchingQuestions = allRecords
        .Where(x => x.Category == category && x.Points == points)
        .ToArray();

    if (matchingQuestions.Length == 0) { return null; }

    // if length is 2, random returns 0 or 1.
    // if length is 3, random returns 0 or 1 or 2, etc.
    int randomChoice = randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, matchingQuestions.Length);
    return matchingQuestions[randomChoice];
}
```

---

### ORIGINAL POST

I've implemented a fully working solution which loads all the csv file into memory as instances of `CsvRecord` class.

The csv file I've created looks like the following. Please note that the header (field names) is important. It should match our property names. If not, we still have a workaround, but I assume they will be the same.

The csv data is expected to be comma separated by default. This behavior can also be changed.

```
Id,Category,Points,Question,Answer
1,History,100,Question 1 (History) - 100 Points,Answer 1 (History) - 100 Points
2,History,100,Question 2 (History) - 100 Points,Answer 2 (History) - 100 Points
3,History,200,Question 3 (History) - 200 Points,Answer 3 (History) - 200 Points
4,History,200,Question 4 (History) - 200 Points,Answer 4 (History) - 200 Points
5,History,300,Question 5 (History) - 300 Points,Answer 5 (History) - 300 Points
6,History,300,Question 6 (History) - 300 Points,Answer 6 (History) - 300 Points
7,History,400,Question 7 (History) - 400 Points,Answer 7 (History) - 400 Points
8,History,400,Question 8 (History) - 400 Points,Answer 8 (History) - 400 Points
9,History,500,Question 9 (History) - 500 Points,Answer 9 (History) - 500 Points
10,History,500,Question 10 (History) - 500 Points,Answer 10 (History) - 500 Points
11,Science,100,Question 11 (Science) - 100 Points,Answer 11 (Science) - 100 Points
12,Science,100,Question 12 (Science) - 100 Points,Answer 12 (Science) - 100 Points
13,Science,200,Question 13 (Science) - 200 Points,Answer 13 (Science) - 200 Points
14,Science,200,Question 14 (Science) - 200 Points,Answer 14 (Science) - 200 Points
15,Science,300,Question 15 (Science) - 300 Points,Answer 15 (Science) - 300 Points
16,Science,300,Question 16 (Science) - 300 Points,Answer 16 (Science) - 300 Points
17,Science,400,Question 17 (Science) - 400 Points,Answer 17 (Science) - 400 Points
18,Science,400,Question 18 (Science) - 400 Points,Answer 18 (Science) - 400 Points
19,Science,500,Question 19 (Science) - 500 Points,Answer 19 (Science) - 500 Points
20,Science,500,Question 20 (Science) - 500 Points,Answer 20 (Science) - 500 Points
21,Geography,100,Question 21 (Geography) - 100 Points,Answer 21 (Geography) - 100 Points
22,Geography,100,Question 22 (Geography) - 100 Points,Answer 22 (Geography) - 100 Points
23,Geography,200,Question 23 (Geography) - 200 Points,Answer 23 (Geography) - 200 Points
24,Geography,200,Question 24 (Geography) - 200 Points,Answer 24 (Geography) - 200 Points
```

Then, the following class (which is a complete console application) demonstrates loading the csv file, filtering and selecting the question to ask.

I hope this helps. I've also added some comment lines here and there to explain things.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using System.Linq;

namespace console
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class CsvRecord
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
            public int Points { get; set; }
            public string Question { get; set; }
            public string Answer { get; set; }
        }

        public sealed class CsvRecordMap : ClassMap<CsvRecord>
        {
            public CsvRecordMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.Id);
                Map(m => m.Category);
                Map(m => m.Points);
                Map(m => m.Question);
                Map(m => m.Answer);
            }
        }

        static CsvRecord[] allRecords;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Fill all records into a shared array (allRecords)
            // CSVHelper reads our csv file and creates a CsvRecord
            // instance for each row using our ClassMap implementation
            using (var reader = new StreamReader("data.csv"))
            {
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvRecordMap>();
                    allRecords = csv.GetRecords<CsvRecord>().ToArray();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a category and points to get a random question");

            Console.Write("Category: "); string category = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Points: "); int points = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // using System.LinQ;
            // A simple filter
            CsvRecord[] matchingRecords = allRecords.Where(a => a.Category == category && a.Points == points).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine("{0} records found", matchingRecords.Length);

            // Randomly select one of the two
            Random random = new Random();
            CsvRecord pickedRecord = matchingRecords[random.Next(matchingRecords.Length)];

            Console.WriteLine("Selected: {0}", pickedRecord.Question);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello again. Late response back, but I'm back in a slump. Don't know what to do from here. I've pretty much done your thing, but after looking through your code I noticed that it's not entirely in the way I thought it would. My game is played on Windows Forms and set up just like a standard Jeopardy game. This meaning when you press a button, it should be calling the specified point value and category and under those 2, it can find the 2 questions added and pick random between them. Is there a way to make this possible? 
I've tried to do it solo for days, but no luck.

Comment: Do you have the `static CsvRecord[] allRecords;` in your code?

Comment: What errors? Can you upload your full app somewhere so I can fix?

Comment: I added the required method.

Comment: Here it is. Took a little longer because of some struggles with Guthub...

https://github.com/mathiasfri/JeopardyGameTest

Comment: Of course. Take your time :)

I'm just really grateful for the help!

Comment: It's done. You must be very new to programming, at least to programming with forms. Updating the answer.

Comment: Yes and no. I've been studying in it in school as a subject, but my teacher sucks, so none in my class has learnt alot the past 2 years... It's kinda sad. 

Anyway, thanks alot for the help!

Comment: Just finished the project. Your help is so appreciated, even though you probably had no issues making this. You saved my exam :)

Comment: I am glad for you. Don't let it be just a class or an exam for you. Programming is a way of life. Good luck!

Comment: Of course not! As soon as I graduate, I'm going to invest way more free time in programming.

I have one question though. To make the code more improved and make me not input the points and category for every button, is there a way for the variables "currentCategory" and "currentPoints" get their values from a label and the button.Text?

I've tried a bit, but it's giving me errors, which is understandable - I just could not come up with other solutions.

Comment: string currentCategory = label1.Text;
int currentPoints = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

Values pickedRecord = GetRandomQuestion(currentCategory, currentPoints);

Comment: This is workable. But your button (in the source code that I have) has "Danish 100", both the category and the points. The last statements that you commented here should work if TextBox1.Text has a value that is parsable to integer in it

Comment: I already changed the textbox text to"100" and added the label which has the category "Danish".
It gives me the error "input string was not in the correct format" on the line where i define currentPoints

Comment: My mistake, just noticed i wrote textBox instead of button. Everything works now. Thanks again! :D